# Theme edits by users

Tags: php, edit

i have made an small script to allow users to build they page or contact form in my site

but some friends told me they want add some JS scripts !

so i thinking about allow users to edit header.php file

the file content is - Example

```
<head>
<title>Mysite | user_name</title>
</head>
```

Now i have idea

i will take a copy from the real file ( header.php )

and allow user to edit it

the editable version will be

```
<title>{Mysite} | {user_name}</title>
```

and then , i will use ( str_replace function ) to replace {mysite} by my site title varibal

MY Question is !

if the user posted a php code

example

```
<head>
<title>{Mysite} | {user_name}</title>
<? include /// or echo 'error' or what ever ! ?>
//and some things others
</head>
```

the php code will work ? or will be ignored and used as html only ?

if there is a secure and good another way please tell me !

thank you

Comment: This depends on how you load/read the template. oyu didn't show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `header.php` file, which your users can modify, is included *(using `require` or `include`)* from your PHP code, then, the PHP code it contains will be executed.

In your case, I would rather :

- Use a file name like `header.tpl`, to indicate that this file doesn't contain PHP code, but is indeed some kind of template.
- And I would not use `inclure`/`require` to get the content of that template file, but a simple [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: Thank you pascal i will never include or require the file edited by user ! , i will use database,inputs ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you still want to use `.php` and not something less dangerous for templates, then you should sanitize user input anyway so they don't exploit it.

Perhaps you can start with `strip_tags()` function and using `allowable_tags` argument there

Comment: Thank you very much , ofcourse useful answere <- sorry for my language